# Windows 10 file transfer stuck at 100%

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, network-drive

When trying to copy files from my external drive or a network drive, the file transfer dialog often stays open after the file transfer has presumably been completed. The dialog window is entitled "Completed 100%" and no ongoing file transfers are listed in the dialog window. Yet, when closing the window, Windows Explorer warns of aborting (any) ongoing file transfers. When confirming the warning, the empty "Completed 100%" dialog stays open as before. The whole procedure could be repeated indefinitely, the dialog never closes.

My colleagues who work with the same network drives have never experienced such a problem. Is there a way to fix the behavior?

Windows 10 version 1809 (build 17763.253). The described behavior has been seen even with earlier updates.

Comment: I think nobody knows

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is something going on after the actual data copy, as you talk about windows 10 I would guess that it's the built in antivirus program checking the files (or some other simular program).

If you have extremly many files or folder depth in the same directory it might also be that the filesystem have problem cooping with the load and is taking long time or simply failing..